# How do I initialize a string with an object?

Tags: c++, string

So I was wondering if I could do something like the following in C++.

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class foo
{
    public:
        string bar;
        string baz;

    foo(const string &faz)
    :bar(faz)
    {
    };
};

int main()
{
    const foo foo1("somestring");
    bool isTrue = ((std::string(foo1) == "some string");//This should be true
    return 0;
}
```

How would I make `std::string(foo1)` equal `"some string"`? Is there some special variable name I need to use? Or is there something else I need to be doing? Please tell me if you know

Comment: Well you _could_ add a conversion operator but those are generally relegated to specific situations where they're actually useful.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I thought that was used for `struct`s? Can you specify what you mean in an answer? Please bear with me, I'm a novice.

Comment: `operator string() const { return BLAH; }`

Comment: Hmmmm. The only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is the default access (i.e. private vs. public). A conversion operator is  `operator T() const` where `T` is the type to convert to.

Comment: @NeilKirk Kirk Where would I put that in my code?

Comment: @MattMcNabb did that

Comment: In your class. Maybe you need to read a good C++ book for more practice.

Comment: You could also add `operator ==` with a string parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically got 2 options:

1. add a conversion operator, so that a `foo` can implicitly convert to `string`
2. define `operator==` for `foo`.

The first option may seem attractive at first, but code that uses conversion operators can quickly get out of hand - overload resolution is tricky enough as it is without adding more possible pathways.

The `operator==` version is quite simple (note, by making it a non-member you allow the char array to appear on the left of the `==`):

```
bool operator==( foo const &f1, foo const &f2 )
{
     return f1.bar == f2.bar;
}
```

You would use it like:

```
bool isTrue = (foo1 == "some string");
```

This matches char arrays because `foo` has a converting constructor, and the implicit conversion chain of `char[]` -> `char *` -> `const std::string &` happens.

Comment: Assuming he wants to compare by bar member. It's not actually stated how the comparison should be performed.

Comment: I don't think using conversion operators will get out of hand. I'm only using it to return a single member string of my object. Also, in my actual code, I am required to use `BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL("some string", std::string(foo1));` so I can't use the `operator==` version.